# How to make `slice` the array element by required length and update

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array items, i would like to show items by `3` by `3`. for that i am slicing the items.

and when sliced item appended, on click of sliced item, i would like to update that item as `heading` item.

I have `next` and `prev` link to click. next provides `1` to add and previous provides `-1` reduce the length.

I did my try with some way, but i am not able to get the right way. any help me to get this done?

my code :

```
<div ng-controller="main" class="content">
      <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
      <a ng-click="slide(-1)">Prev</a>
        <h2 ng-repeat="title in titles">{{title}}</h2>
      <a ng-click="slide(1)">Prev</a>
    </div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.required = 3;
  $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
  $scope.titles = $scope.items.slice(0,3);
  $scope.heading = $scope.titles[0];

  $scope.slide = function (num) {
    console.log(num);
  }

})
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tGKtWofCOaZlBUSLn31p?p=preview)

Comment: on click of prev(i.e -1) which element do u want to remove??? Please be clear...

Comment: I don't want to remove anything. i am doing slide process.  so all need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would be something like below

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="main" class="content">
  <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
  <a ng-click="prev(-1)">Prev</a>
    <h2 ng-repeat="title in titles">{{title}}</h2>
  <a ng-click="next(1)">Next</a>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
myApp.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.required = 3;
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

  $scope.titles = angular.copy($scope.items).slice(0, 3);
  $scope.heading = $scope.titles[0];

  $scope.startIndex = 0;
  $scope.next = function(num) {
    if ($scope.startIndex < $scope.items.length) {
      $scope.startIndex = $scope.startIndex + 2;
      $scope.titles = Array.prototype.slice.call($scope.items, ++$scope.startIndex, $scope.startIndex + 3);
    }
  }

  $scope.prev = function(num) {
    if ($scope.startIndex > 0) {
      $scope.startIndex = $scope.startIndex - 2;
      $scope.titles = Array.prototype.slice.call($scope.items, --$scope.startIndex, $scope.startIndex + 3);

    }
  }

  $scope.updateHeading = function(item) {
    $scope.heading = item;
  }

})
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sPxO4A10hObrlId3hrmf?p=preview)

Comment: No, i want to update by next set of array, eg. 1,2,3 first set and second is 4,5,6, and third set should be `7,8,9,` last one `0`. and any one of the element clicked example:`1` or `7` or `9` the heading should be updated with that element. if 7 clicked the heading should be 7.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice` copies a portion of the source array, so your `angular.copy` call is not necessary.

Comment: @user2024080 do you want something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/UHUryYHZYo9eAXF4Wdvo?p=preview ?

Comment: on first i am getting `1,2,3` but `4` is not there. and without clicking the `h2` element i don't want to update the heading.

Comment: @user2024080 please do update your question first..you are adding things as I answering.. First clear the requirement

Comment: I updated here. can you check http://plnkr.co/edit/aQpYxpd8fgurcuadmlk7?p=preview - confirm me?

Comment: @user2024080 oh thats nice..let me change one thing use `Array.prototype.slice` instead of making copy of an array

Comment: here is updated copy http://plnkr.co/edit/f8SngdpZE9YaQMoc7Zpp?p=preview as good way suggested by @NoahFreitas

Comment: sure. show me the correct approach and simplest. thanks for your efforts. by the way what is different from using $copy with `prototype` method?

Comment: @user2024080 yeah I updated with correct approach..you can refer that..Thanks..Glad to help you.. Cheers :)